# Align table items to the right using td colspan? (HTML)

Tags: php, html, html-table

So basically I created a calendar in PHP and HTML. All of the days are stored in a table. But when I render the calendar in my localhost browser, the colspan function doesn't appear to work on the first row and it starts from the beginning, although the rest of the calendar lines up nicely.

[image: Illustrated here,]

You can see that the first row of elements doesn't align to the right, which is what a normal calendar would do, even though I used colspan on it.

here is the code:

````
    $output = '<table class = "Calendar">';     //The Calendar is a table instead of being made of individual items.

    $output .= '<caption class = "monthName">' . $this->date_info ['month'] . ' ' . $this->year . '</caption>';
    $output .= '<tr>';    //new table row

    //creates days of the week header for each day in the array
    foreach ( $this->weekdays as $days ){   //for every day in the weekdays array, setting each of them AS a day ($day)
      $output .= '<th class = "header">' . $days . '</th>';
    }

    //IF the first day of a month doesnt fall on a sunday then use COLSPAN to fill the BEGINNING SPACE
    if ($this->dayOfWeek > 0){
      $output .= '<td colspan="' . $this->dayOfWeek . '"></td>';
    }

    //Start the num_days counter
    $output .= '<tr></tr>';   //space calender BELOW the days
    $current_day = 1;```


(later code)
```  //Increment counters
    $current_day++;
    $this->dayOfWeek++;

    }
    // Once num_days counter stops, if day of week counter is not 7, then fill the remaining space on the row uing COLSPAN
    if ($this->dayOfWeek != 7) {    //Resets at 7
      $remaining_days = 7 - $this->dayOfWeek;    //Amount of remaining days in the week
      $output .= '<td colspan="' . $remaining_days .'"></td>';   //span for the remaining days in the week
    }
    //Close final row, close table

    $output .= '</tr>';
    $output .= '</table>';
````

Comment: Where is `$this->dayOfWeek` set? It also looks like you create an empty row immediately after making your blank leading td, so that would start you from the beginning anyway. I'm confused.

Comment: When you look at the html source of the page, does the order of your first row and its cells seem correct?

Comment: your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags are not generated in a valid order, check the resulting html, that should help

Comment: ```  $this->dayOfWeek = $this->date_info['wday'];   //get the info including the day of the week that <given_date> falls on